# How extract text from pdf file in React native

Tags: react-native

We need to extract text from pdf file in React native. Please suggest me any library or source code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435198/how-to-extract-content-from-pdf-file-in-react-native

Comment: RNFS.readAsync is not a function

Comment: If we use pdf-parse library, we are getting 'fs could not be found'

Comment: Some days ago I needed to extract text from pdf file using react-native, I try some libraries but none worked like expected for me, therefore I started create a new one library to extract texts from pdf using regex, this is on initial stage but could be util. https://1fabiopereira.github.io/react-native-pdf-extractor/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-pdf2json](https://github.com/abhineet255/react-native-pdf2json) repo to read pdf content into json like

```
let fs = require('fs'),
PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

let pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
     fs.writeFile("./pdf2json/test/F1040EZ.json", JSON.stringify(pdfData));
});

pdfParser.loadPDF("./pdf2json/test/pdf/fd/form/F1040EZ.pdf");
```

You can also use [react-native-pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib)